# backpacking on ESTA VWP for 75 days a problem at border crossing?

Tags: usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program

I want to go to the US for 2.5 months and I'm a little scared I will have difficulty getting in because it's for so long. I'm going to backpack and stay with friends, i have two inland flights as well, will spend two weeks in 4 different cities and then i want to go for a hike, maybe rent a car. I'm a student but I don't have employment because of that. has anyone travelled there for so long and experienced any problems? I'm female, white and from germany.. also don't know how much money I will have to proof. any experience would be appreciated